# Azure AD Verifiable Credential from where i can get public key private key values?

Tags: azure-active-directory, decentralized-identity, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

I m working on one of solution with azure VC where i will need to use
private key pubic key of azure VC.

as we follow azure VC steps i have created key vault and i have seen sign in and other key are generated.

but i want to use same public key private key which is used by Azure VC in my other application logic ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure KeyVault instance that VC is using for other purposes if you grant your app access via access policies. Then to use the same keys, you follow KeyVault´s documentation for keys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide#apis-and-sdks-for-keys